# Different type of data in SDLNet_TCP_Send

Tags: c++, networking, sdl

Is it also possible to send any other type of variable then char[] using SDLNet_TCP_Send and SDLNet_TCP_Recv? If so what should maxlength be equal to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function sprintf and sscanf is the way